# how to set minimum of passed parameters number to a function in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```kotlin
fun TextView.setShadowDetails(shadowColor : Int? = null, shadowDx : Float? = null, shadowDy: Float? = null , shadowRadius : Float? = null){
        setShadowLayer(shadowRadius ?: getShadowRadius(),shadowDx ?: getShadowDx(),shadowDy ?: getShadowDy(),shadowColor ?: getShadowColor())
    }
```

Is there a way to get a build error if no parameter is passed to this function?
That is, can the minimum number of parameters transferred to this function be set to one? (In some cases I may need to access at least two parameters)

If that's possible, Kotlin is truly a wonderful language!

**Tip :**
*Please only notify me if you have a answer other than *[function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68438427/11819708)* .*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be simple overloading, like you could do in Java as well.
So not sure if you're interessted in this,a s it's no fancy Kotlin feature.

Possible solution:

```
fun doSomething(number1: Int, number2: Int? = null, text: String? = null) {
    //do sth
}


fun doSomething(number1: Int? = null, number2: Int, text: String? = null) {
    //do sth
}

fun doSomething(number1: Int? = null, number2: Int? = null, text: String) {
    //do sth
}

doSomething(1)
```

so here I overload the function and always have one parameter as nonnull. This way you're not able to call the function without any parameter.

Comment: thank you for answer !  

This is a good answer and I really do not know why didn't it in think of me?! As you said, this feature is also available in Java. But I thought there was an easier way to do that in Kotlin!

I thought there would be an annotation to make it easier. With this calculus I have to write 12 separate function for 2 limit and 4 parameters : 3 * 4 = 12! ):  

You can count them like math problems, and I do not like that. Of course, I have to thank God, because in Java the same number reached 36! (⊙_⊙;)

Comment: I am happy to help. You're right the number of fuction overloads you need to write grows very fast if you need at least 2, 3, 4, ... parameters to be not null. But I do not know a more elegant solution...
If you don't mind please upvote my answer :)

Comment: Your answer is correct. 

I'm happy if other people have a better answer that is consistent with my vision, Let me know .

Thanks !